# Почему запрос "groups.get" возвращает не валидный ответ?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, android-vksdk

Я делаю запрос к `VK api` напрямую передавая `token`

Т.е. `https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?fields=photo_50&access_token=MY_TOKEN&filter=admin%2C%20editor%2C%20moder&extended=1`
Т.е. вот [дока по апи](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=groups.get)
Но ответ нельзя serialize в объект используя `Gson`, т.к. в ответе в массиве есть `int`  т.е. ответ вида

```
{
    "response": [
        2,
        {
            "gid": 59295,
            "name": "Создание",
            "screen_name": "book",
            "is_closed": 0,
            "type": "group",
            "photo_50": "https://pp.userapi.com/qwvD6SPkYzo.jpg"
        },
        {
            "gid": 57150,
            "name": "Массаж",
            "screen_name": "club10450",
            "is_closed": 2,
            "type": "group",
            "photo_50": "https://pp.userapi.com/ZKnmRkS1izs.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Как мне сделать serialize в объект используя `Gson`, такого вида ответ?

Comment: *"Почему запрос “groups.get” возвращает не валидный ответ?"* -- нипочему, так как ответ **валидный**.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, нужно было добавить номер версии апи в параметры запроса `v=5.61`